# symfony - embedForm and form widgets not saving

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have an embeddedForm that I am trying to configure the widgets for.

Currently I am just outputting the form in a `_form.php` template like:

```
<?php echo $form ?>
```

This is great, but I'd like to have my form fields in a particular order, so I thought I'd try:

```
<?php echo $form['firstname']->renderRow() ?> 
<?php echo $form['lastname']->renderRow() ?> 
<?php echo $form['email_address']->renderRow() ?>
```

This gives me an invalid widget error.

Now I have 2 forms, one is a basic form, that simply embeds another form.

```
<?php
class labSupportForm extends sfGuardUserAdminForm
{
   public function configure()
   {
     $form = new labSupportProfileForm($this->getObject()->getProfile());
     $this->embedForm('profile', $form);

   unset($this['is_super_admin'], $this['is_admin'], $this['permissions_list'], $this['groups_list']);

   $this->widgetSchema['profile'] = $form->getWidgetSchema();
   $this->validatorSchema['profile'] = $form->getValidatorSchema();
 }

 public function save($con = null)
 {
   $user = parent::save($con);
   if (!$user->hasGroup('Lab Support'))
   {
     $user->addGroupByName('Lab Support');
     $user->save();
   }
   return $user;
 }
}
```

and:

```
<?php
class labSupportProfileForm extends sfGuardUserProfileForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    unset($this['email_new'],
          $this['validate_at'],
          $this['validate'],
          $this['address_1'],
          $this['address_2'],
          $this['city'],
          $this['country'],
          $this['postcode'],
          $this['created_at'],
          $this['updated_at'],  
          $this['user_id'],   
          $this['is_super_admin'], 
          $this['is_admin'], 
          $this['permissions_list'], 
          $this['groups_list']);
   }
}
```

But If I add the widget/validator to the `labSupportForm` and save, the `firstname` value doesn't save.

Am I doing something wrong here, as I would have thought this value would save.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to write $this->widgetSchema['profile'] = $form->getWidgetSchema(), this is automatically handled by embedForm method, same for validator schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render a form by fields, you have to explicitly call $form->renderHiddenFields(). For example:

```
<?php echo form_tag_for($form, '@url') ?>
  <table>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
          <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <?php echo $form['username']->renderRow() ?>
      <?php echo $form['profile_form']->renderRow() ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Also, beware calling embedded form name the same as relation name (e.g. 'profile') or you will have [troubles](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/81557/) when saving it. Just add '_form' suffix and you will be safe:

```
$this->embedForm('profile_form', $form);
```

If you want to keep a linear display structure of your form fields, you should render them explicitly according to your widget schema:

```
      <?php echo $form['username']->renderRow() ?>
      <?php echo $form['profile_form']['first_name']->renderRow() ?>
      <?php echo $form['profile_form']['last_name']->renderRow() ?>
```

Or you can do it automatically for all fields of an embedded form:

```
    <?php foreach ($form['profile_form'] as $field): ?>
      <?php if (!$field->isHidden()): ?>
        <?php echo $field->renderRow() ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `$this->saveEmbeddedForms()` in the `labSupportForm` save method